# aside dentro do header

Tags: javascript, css, html5, aplicação-web, semântica

Olá, gostaria de saber se é semântico utilizar a tag `<aside></aside>` dentro do head em um menu que é fixo no cabeçalho da página ao lado da logo do site, na minha conclusão penso que seja errado pois a tag `<header>` é uma tag que indica uma seção da pagina, no caso a parte superior, mas seria errado inserir apenas o menu `<nav>` direto no `<header>`.

Comment: Acho que a falta do uso da interrogação (`?`) no texto da sua pergunta deixou ela meio confusa. Não se sabe bem onde é uma pergunta e onde é uma afirmação.

Comment: Ao meu ver Aside é um conteúdo classificado como complementar, ou a parte, e ele pode estar presente em Sctions, Articles, Headres, etc, ele é um elemento secundário, mas que faz parte de onde está inserido.

Comment: cara foi mal era pressa mesmo vou passar a prestar mais atenção a isso

Answer (score 0):

Caso a tag em questão for a `<header ... />`, sim seria semântico desde que a estrutura proposta seja algo como o exemplo da própria w3c.
http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-header-element

```
<article>

  <header>
    <h1>Flexbox: The definitive guide</h1>

    <aside>

      <header>
        <h2>About the author: Wes McSilly</h2>
        <p><a href="./wes-mcsilly/">Contact him! (Why would you?)</a></p>
      </header>

      <p>Expert in nothing but Flexbox. Talented circus sideshow.</p>
    </aside>

  </header>

  <p><ins>The guide about Flexbox was supposed to be here, but it
    turned out Wes wasn’t a Flexbox expert either.</ins></p>

</article>
```

Voce pode tambem ler a documentacao na qual lhe da maiores informacoes sobre a utilizacao destas e outras tags em:
http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#sections

Answer (score 0):

## Descrição oficial

[Esta página](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sections.html#the-header-element) do W3C, descreve o elemento header da seguinte forma:

> The header element represents introductory content for its nearest
>   ancestor main element or sectioning content or sectioning root
>   element. A header typically contains a group of introductory or
>   navigational aids.

**Traduzindo:**

> O elemento header representa conteúdo introdutório para o seu
>   ancestral principal mais próximo ou secionamento de conteúdo ou
>   secionamento do elemento raíz. Um header, tipicamente, contém um grupo
>   de auxiliares introdutórios ou navegacionais.

Portanto, essa sua afirmação não é, exatamente, correta:

> ...é uma tag que indica uma seção da pagina, no caso a parte superior...

Isso porque, de maneira semântica, o elemento é usado para apresentar um conteúdo introdutório, mas não apenas para fazer uma seção da parte superior.

## Mãe, quem é meu pai?

O [MDN fala](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside) que a tag `<aside>` pode ter qualquer elemento pai que aceite *flow content*.

> Qualquer elemento que aceita conteudo de fluxo. Note que um elemento
>   `<aside>` nao deve ser descendente de um elemento `<address>`.

Além disso, [esta página](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sections.html#the-header-element) do W3C (exemplo 20) comprova o que foi dito, com o seguinte código:

```
<article>
  <header>
    <h1>Flexbox: The definitive guide</h1>
    <aside>
      <header>
        <h2>About the author: Wes McSilly</h2>
        <p><a href="./wes-mcsilly/">Contact him! (Why would you?)</a></p>
      </header>
      <p>Expert in nothing but Flexbox. Talented circus sideshow.</p>
    </aside>
  </header>
  <p><ins>The guide about Flexbox was supposed to be here, but it
    turned out Wes wasn’t a Flexbox expert either.</ins></p>
</article>
```

## Conclusão

Dado isso, e acrescentando, costumo pensar que `<aside>` vem de uma frase do inglês: *aside from content* (à parte do conteúdo).

Assim, percebe-se claramente que pode ser usada "ao lado" de conteúdo, não importando se é um parágrafo ou header.

Comment: vlw, ajudou bastante ainda to aprendendo por isso dos gaffes

Comment: Cara, você fez uma pergunta pra aprender. Gafe seria não querer aprender.